# issue related to space after link

Tags: asp.net

I am generating a link using below code

```
string EncryptPath = Common.Encrypt(Path);
        string SourceLinkPath= string.Empty;

     if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("Image.txt")))
        {
            SourceLinkPath  = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath     ("Image.txt"));
        }


          string link2 = SourceLinkPath + EncryptPath;

         TxtPathLink2.Text = link2;
```

the link is generating but it is giving space after sourcepath. OUTPUT like 
**http://18.10.10.11/test/View.aspx?Value=
67534ERT**

i want to generate like **http://18.10.10.11/test/View.aspx?Value=67534ERT**
How can i generate link in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.txt` file probably has a whitespace you are missing.

Change `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath     ("Image.txt"))`

To:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("Image.txt")).Trim()
```

`String.Trim()` removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the `String` object.

Comment: Note `EncryptPath` might also have a space.